# foreach loop and array_merge not matching correctly

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, array-merge

I have the following two arrays that I am trying to merge into one where a common order_id is found:

$orders array:

```
[0] => Array (
    [order_id] => 45145
    [customers_email_address] => test@test.com
    [customers_name] => test name
    )
[1] => Array (
    [order_id] => 45136
    [customers_email_address] => test@yahoo.com
    [customers_name] => test name
    )
[2] => Array (
    [order_id] => 45117
    [customers_email_address] => test@yahoo.com
    [customers_name] => test name
    )
[3] => Array (
    [order_id] => 44959
    [customers_email_address] => test@gmail.com
    [customers_name] => test name
    )
[4] => Array (
    [order_id] => 44938
    [customers_email_address] => test@hotmail.com
    [customers_name] => t
    )
```

$chitchattracking array:

```
[1] => Array (
    [order_id] => 44938
    [carrier_tracking_code] => 9205590221582717655498
    )
[2] => Array (
    [order_id] => 44854
    [carrier_tracking_code] => 92055902215827
    )
```

in the above array samples there is a match of the order_id: 44938

Here is my code that is checking for the match, and put it into a new array $tracked:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if (($key = array_search($order['order_id'], array_column($chitchattracking, 'order_id'))) !== false) {
        $tracked[] = array_merge( $order, $chitchattracking[$key]);
    }
}
```

somehow i really messed this up and it matched the wrong order_ids and posted the incorrect tracking numbers. further, when I run the code with this limited amount, it is not even finding the match.

Comment: Is there not a `0` key in your `$chitchattracking` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly being caused by the fact that `array_column` returns an array that is numerically indexed starting at 0, *regardless* of the keys of the input array. So if the input array is not also numerically indexed starting at 0, the key returned by `array_search` will not necessarily match a key in the input array (this is why your code won't run at all with the sample data in your question). The easiest way to work around this is to re-index `$chitchattracking` by `order_id`, then you can do a simple `isset` check to control the push to `$tracking`:

```
$tracking = array();
$chitchat = array_column($chitchattracking, null, 'order_id');
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $order_id = $order['order_id'];
    if (isset($chitchat[$order_id])) {
        $tracking[] = array_merge($order, $chitchat[$order_id]);
    }
}
print_r($tracking);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => 44938
            [customers_email_address] => test@hotmail.com
            [customers_name] => t
            [carrier_tracking_code] => 9.2055902215827E+21
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uO1eW)

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing that out Im frustrated I did not realize the array didnt start at 0. that array was generated from some json, and I am trying to figure out why it doesn't start at 0.

Comment: and I found why, thanks for pointing that out and for giving me the option to re-index!

Comment: @Sackling cool - that's a bonus. Note that even with the indexing fixed this code will be significantly faster than the code you posted in the question as it only calls `array_column` once and has no calls to `array_search` (which is *much* slower than a key lookup).